# Check if a hive table is partitioned on a given column

Tags: hadoop, hive, hiveql

I have a list of hive tables , of which some are partitioned. Given a column I need to check if a particular table is partitioned on that column or not. 
I have searched and found that *desc formatted tablename* would result in all the details of the table. 
Since I have to iterate over all the tables and get the list , desc formatted would not help.
Is there any other way this can be done.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can connect directly to metastore and query it:

```
metastore=# select d."NAME" as DATABASE, 
  t."TBL_NAME" as TABLE, 
  p."PKEY_NAME" as PARTITION_KEY 
  from "PARTITION_KEYS" p 
  join "TBLS" t on p."TBL_ID"=t."TBL_ID" 
  join "DBS" d on t."DB_ID"=d."DB_ID";

 database |    table    | partition_key
----------+-------------+---------------
 default  | src_union_1 | ds
 default  | cbo_t1      | dt
 default  | cbo_t2      | dt
```

The exact syntax of querying your metastore depends on your particular choice of metastore (in my case is a PostgreSQL one).